# executing command from child_process.exec and cmd

Tags: node.js, cmd, child-process

In my Node.js program, I would like to know if a specific port is used so I execute the command below with child_process.exec (example with port 3001) :

```
netstat -na | find "3001"
```

If the port is used I get informations about the port as expected but If it is not used I get the following error:

[image]

I don't understand why I get this error because when I run the same command in cmd, If the port is not used it doesn't throw error:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong ?

Node version: v10.16.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this. I have created API you can directly call.

This will return the result data.

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

function os_func() {
    this.execCommand = function(cmd, callback) {
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            callback(stdout);
        });
    }
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("inside get");
    var os = new os_func();
    os.execCommand('netstat -na | find "3001"', function (returnvalue) {
      res.end(returnvalue)
});

});
```